# spring application - both @Configuration and Spring <beans> XML in the same application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to have a Spring application with *both* Spring  XML that defines some of the beans and also a @Configuration class that defines other beans?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Spring Boot and Spring 5.x will drive you away from XML and towards annotations.  It's a good idea to follow the trend and write using the proper idiom.

None of my Spring Boot apps use XML.  That was part of Rod Johnson's original vision for Interface 21/Spring, but annotations have won the day.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, but it is not recommended. Bean configuration should be consistent to be either all in @Annotations or in XML files.

Is there any specific reason that you want to put some bean configuration in XML rather than in @Configuration class?